# How Youtube ContentID performs video fingerprinting to identify copied video

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, video-processing, fingerprinting

I am trying to build a system exactly same as youtube contentID which will generate fingerprints of the video and will search the fingerprint in the database. I want to know what fingerprinting algorithm or method is used by Youtube ContentID to generate the fingerprints and compare the fingerprints and how it performs fingerprint searching in database

Comment: Did you try emailing or asking in Google forums, what their exact algorithm is? Realistically it should be two methods, one for handling pixels and another one for handling audio frequencies. You'll have to **reverse-engineer** it. Why not try something basic like **Perceptual Hashing** and fine-tune your result (via other functions) to match the Youtube results? Google might even be using AI nowadays to power their Youtube content analysis tools.

Comment: Basically instead of 1 year of research just to copy Youtube, create a solution that works for you and can match your stored video content.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the exact algorithm is known. You could use scene detection and chunking to create bounded-size chunks of video and audio. Then, you could use locality sensitive hashing techniques to index these chunks, so that similar chunks receive identical hashes. However, this is not straightforward and subject to active research.